# Tell the server if a change happened - express, react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

Here's the situation:
[image]

I have the main component (App.js), which GETs the database from the server (with LoadData()). Then process, and pass it through the Components. If a new child has been created for a Component, the component does two things: POST-s the new element's properties to the server, then the server pushes it to the database. Synchronously, if a new element created, the Component passes through it's props to the parents all the way up to the App, which then calls the loadData() again. The problem is, that the loadData() is called earlier, than the server pushes the new data to the database. My question is that how can i tell the server (or the App) to wait to get data until the new data receives, if a change happened on the database?

Comment: Try https://socket.io/

Comment: And how socket.io can help me for my problem? I read the documentation, but i don't see any solution.